# IntelliJ + Gradle + SpringLoaded

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-loaded

I'm trying to add SpringLoaded to project which uses gradle, but hot swapping doesn't work. Here is build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

//plugins
//{
//    id 'fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin' // version '0.11.0-beta'
//}

ext
{
    mainClass = 'net.elenx.Epomis'

    springBoot = '1.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    springLoaded = '1.2.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    vaadin = '7.6.8'
}

configurations
{
    springLoadedPath
}

dependencies /** APACHE LICENCE v2.0 **/
{
    /** SPRING **/
    springLoadedPath "org.springframework:springloaded:${springLoaded}"
    compile configurations.springLoadedPath

    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:+"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${springBoot}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBoot}"

    /** DATABASE **/
    compile "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:+"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.10.2.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBoot}"

    /** UTILS **/
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
    compile "commons-net:commons-net:+"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:+"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:+"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:+"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:+"
    compile "javax.mail:mail:+"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:+"
    compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:+'

    /** ASPECTS **/
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:+"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:+"
    compile "cglib:cglib:+"
    compile "cglib:cglib-nodep:+"

    /** FRONTEND **/
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:+"
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:${vaadin}"
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-client:${vaadin}"
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-push:${vaadin}"
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-server:${vaadin}"
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:${vaadin}"
    compile "com.vaadin:vaadin-spring:+"
    compile "com.vaadin.tapio:googlemaps:+"

    /** TESTS **/
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:+"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:+"
    testCompile "org.objenesis:objenesis:+"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:+"
}

dependencies /** LGPL v2.1 LICENCE **/
{
    /** DATABASE **/
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:+"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:+"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:+"
}

dependencies /** MIT LICENCE **/
{
    /** UTILS **/
    compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:+"
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:+"
}

dependencies /** ECLIPSE PUBLIC LICENCE **/
{
    /** ASPECTS **/
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:+"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:+"
}

dependencies /** BSD LICENCE **/
{
    /** DATABASE **/
    compile "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:+"

    /** ASPECT **/
    compile "com.jcabi:jcabi-aspects:+"

    /** TESTS **/
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:+"
}

dependencies /** POSTGRESQL (MIT/BSD LIKE) LICENCE **/
{
    /** DATABASE **/
    compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:+"
}

configurations
{
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}

String epomisVersion = 'v1'

group 'net.elenx'
version epomisVersion

jar
{
    baseName = 'Epomis'
    version = epomisVersion
}

buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot-libs' }
    }

    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:+'
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:+'
    }
}

repositories
{
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot-libs' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons' }
}

mainClassName = mainClass
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-javaagent:${configurations.springLoadedPath.asPath}", '-noverify']

eclipse
{
    classpath
    {
        containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
        containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

compileJava
{
    options.fork = true
    options.incremental = true
}

idea
{
    module
    {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

war
{
    archiveName = 'ROOT.war'
    destinationDir = file('webapps')
}

task stage \
{
    dependsOn build
}
```

I also added vm option `-javaagent:PathToFile -noverify`, `checked Make project automatically` in file -> settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement -> compiler and checked `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` in registry but hot swapping still does not work and I don't now why.